# Can open source hbase work on Cloudera distribution of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, cloudera

I have a Cloudera Distribution installed as a 5 Node Cluster. Now I do not want to use the Hbase parcel that comes with cloudera,

but instead I want to use only HDFS from the cloudera setup and an opensource version of Hbase.

So my question is will this work or I will have to install normal open-source version of Apache Hadoop for HDFS and then go forward with the Opensource version of Apache Hbase on top of it.

Comment: short to say, yes. however, it depends on the version of hbase and hdfs you use. generally, hbase only use hdfs api to write file.

Comment: The Cloudera parcel is probably only meant for CDH installation. In any case, Cloudera does use the open source Hbase, I thought? Or they use Accumulo?

Comment: If you want to go all open source, though, why Cloudera and not Hortonworks?

Comment: I think perhaps you are misunderstanding parcels. A parcel is just metadata-enhanced packaging that makes it easier to deploy CDH (including Apache HBase) bits across your cluster using Cloudera Manager (which is optional). But, you can choose to install CDH as a tarball instead.

Comment: why do you want that ? If you want to use some spesific version of hbase instead of that comes with cdh, you can do that with cloudera too.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the version of hadoop matches the version of used by the hadoop client used by the version of hbase matches it should all work.